# Haskell - Couldn't match expected type

Tags: haskell, custom-data-type

So I am trying to create a simple text editor in Haskell. I have defined a custom data type 'TextEditor' which consists of two char sets one acts as all the characters before the cursor then next is all the characters after the cursor. I've initialized this with some text to begin with.

```
import Data.List
import System.IO

data TextEditor = TextEditor([Char],[Char]) deriving (Show)

inputLine :: TextEditor
inputLine = TextEditor("The quick br", "own fox")

moveCursorLeft :: TextEditor -> TextEditor
moveCursorLeft (TextEditor (b, a)) = (TextEditor (b++ [head (a)]) , tail(a))
```

I am getting this error when I try to load.

```
Test.hs:10:38: error:
Couldn't match expected type `TextEditor' with actual type `(TextEditor, [Char])'
    * In the expression: (TextEditor (b ++ [head (a)]), tail (a))
      In an equation for `moveCursorLeft':
          moveCursorLeft (TextEditor (b, a))
            = (TextEditor (b ++ [head (a)]), tail (a))

Test.hs:10:51: error:
    * Couldn't match expected type `([Char], [Char])' with actual type `[Char]'
    * In the first argument of `TextEditor', namely `(b ++ [head (a)])'
      In the expression: TextEditor (b ++ [head (a)])
      In the expression: (TextEditor (b ++ [head (a)]), tail (a))
```

I am very new to Haskell so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try `TextEditor ((b++ [head (a)]) , tail(a))`
Looks like you didn't place your `()` correctly

Comment: Just out of interest, what do you think will happen when I call `moveCursorLeft (TextEditor ("abc",""))`?

Comment: It looks like you want a [zipper](http://learnyouahaskell.com/zippers) (scroll down to "Focusing on lists").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line is wrong:

```
moveCursorLeft (TextEditor (b, a)) = (TextEditor (b++ [head (a)]) , tail(a))
--                                   ^ Why is this bracket here?
```

it should be:

```
moveCursorLeft (TextEditor (b, a)) = TextEditor ((b ++ [head a]) , tail a)
--                                              ^ It should be here.
```

Note also that I have removed some brackets for the sake of being more idiomatic and readable Haskell.

In general you should avoid using tuples (and therefore this issue) by defining your data like so:

```
data TextEditor = TextEditor [Char] [Char] deriving (Show)
```

Then (omitting other lines) the problematic line would become

```
moveCursorLeft (TextEditor b a) = TextEditor (b ++ [head a]) (tail a)
-- Much cleaner!
```

Remember that in Haskell, functions are called like `function arg1 arg2`, not `function(arg1, arg2)`.

Comment: Thank you very much this worked! Legend :)

Answer (score 5):

You write in the second clause:

```
(TextEditor (b++ [head (a)]) , tail(a))
```

But that means that you do not construct a `TextEditor` object, but a `(TextEditor, String)` 2-tuple (although the first element is still malformed). Indeed:

```
(TextEditor (b++ [head (a)]) , tail(a))
```

You probably are looking for:

```
TextEditor (b++ [head (a)] , tail(a))
```

Nevertheless this is still not a good idea: it is possible that `a` is an empty list, and hence has no `head` or `tail`.

Usually it is better to perform pattern matching here:

```
moveCursorRight :: TextEditor -> TextEditor
moveCursorRight (t@TextEditor ([], b)) = t  -- I think?
moveCursorRight (TextEditor ((a:as), b)) = TextEditor (b ++ [a] , as)
```

But now it is still quite inefficient, since appending takes *O(n)* time. A common technique is to use two lists, where the first one is reversed, so `TextEditor ([1, 4, 2], [5, 1, 3, 0, 2])` would then mean `241|51302` (with `|` the cursor).

We can then write it like:

```
-- In case we reverse the first item of the 2-tuple
moveCursorRight :: TextEditor -> TextEditor
moveCursorRight (t@TextEditor (b, [])) = t
moveCursorRight (TextEditor (b, (a:as))) = TextEditor ((a:b) , as)
```

Note that this is actually moving a cursor to the *right*, in all fucntions, since we pop from the right element of the tuple, and push to the left.